# facebook ios app ui

Tags: ios, facebook, user-interface

Below the screenshot of facebook app on iOS.

I'm curious about the "status, photo, check in" bar buttons, they'll disappear while scrolling down, and appear again while scrolling to the top. Is there any handy framework or open source project can do this?

And the rectangle below which looks and acts a little like a tableview cell, but I think it isn't? or actually by customizing tableview cell can have the same visual effects?

[image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6931090/images/IMG_0169.PNG]

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the "status, photo, checkin" bar, the below should help:

[UIScrollViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UITableView, place the buttons in header view of the row-less first section, and the stream in the rows of the header-less second section.